# Optimizing accesing dicts in python

Tags: python, dictionary

First things first: **Python 3.5** and the next libraries: json, urllib, from urllib import request

I have been trying to accomplish something on two different ways (so far) and I find issues on both of them. Could anyone tell me how would you code it?

The code needs to translate information from the next list of dictionaries using the API of GuildWars2 to get the name and position of each of those objects.

```
ids = [{'traits': [1451, 1338, 1437], 'id': 4}, {'traits': [1471, 1482, 1711], 'id': 11}, {'traits': [2049, 2011, 1928], 'id': 18}]
```

**First try:** (This works perfectly, and there's a picture at the end of this post showing the result. However, the issue here is that it creates 12 requests to the server, and waiting for it to answer takes more time than it should. There's a cap on requests per minute on those servers so I'd like to code it with the minimum needed).

```
specializations_items = []
for i in ids:
    webpage_stored = request.urlopen("https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/specializations/"+str(i['id'])+"?lang=es").read().decode('utf8')
    api_specialization_data = json.loads(webpage_stored)
    api_specialization_name = api_specialization_data["name"]
    translated_traits = []
    numeric_traits = []
    for j in i['traits']:
        webpage_stored = request.urlopen("https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/traits/"+str(j)+"?lang=es").read().decode('utf8')
        api_trait = json.loads(webpage_stored)
        translated_traits.append(api_trait['name'])
        for k in api_specialization_data['major_traits']:
            if j == k:
                numeric_traits.append(str(api_specialization_data['major_traits'].index(k)+1))
    numeric_traits_new = []
    for l in numeric_traits:
        l = l.replace("9", "3").replace("8", "2").replace("7", "1").replace("6", "3").replace("5", "2").replace("4", "1")
        numeric_traits_new.append(l)
    specializations_items.append("[b]"+api_specialization_name+" ("+"".join(numeric_traits_new)+"):[/b] "+", ".join(translated_traits)+".")
return "\n".join(specializations_items)
```

**Second try:** (Cool, just 2 requests to the server, but the issue here is that it's Looping Hell. Also, another issue is that I'm not even sure how to assign the numeric info with the positioning of each trait (that part is unfinished):

```
# Note: Each of the next 2 vars are json.loads dicts of those websites. It's unnecesary long to paste the dicts in here, so just click on the links.
api_traits = https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/traits%3Fids=1451%2C%201338%2C%201437%2C%2C1471%2C%201482%2C%201711%2C%2C2049%2C%202011%2C%201928%26lang=es
api_specializations = https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/specializations%3Fids=4%2C11%2C18%26lang=es

numeric_traits = []
for j in api_specializations:
    for m in j['major_traits']:
        for n in api_traits:
            if n['id'] == m:
                numeric_traits.append(str(j['major_traits'].index(n['id'])+1)+n['name'])
for i in ids:
    for j in api_specializations:
        if i['id'] == j['id']:
            i['name'] = j['name']
    for k in api_traits:
        for l in i['traits']:
            if l == k['id']:
                i['traits'].remove(l)
                i['traits'].append(k['name'])
print(numeric_traits) #Not finished, I don't think using so much loops is a good idea.
```

**Desired output:**

[image: Desired Output]

**Bonus:**

I will provide 2 different ids more just in case you want to check different outputs with different ids:

```
ids = [{'traits': [296, 325, 1510], 'id': 31}, {'traits': [232, 1502, 226], 'id': 41}, {'traits': [1952, 2015, 1986], 'id': 48}]
ids = [{'traits': [815, 816, 801], 'id': 39}, {'traits': [1876, 1844, 778], 'id': 19}, {'traits': [2020, 2031, 1919], 'id': 34}]
```

**So...**

What is the best way to accomplish my task, in a way that it doesn't create unnecessary server requests, and gets the desired results without me getting crazy because of loops inside loops inside loops inside loops (which is also slow)?

Comment: Where do the numbers 221, 333, and 111 come from? I didn't see them anywhere in the JSON.

Comment: Oh I forgot to explain that. The JSON files for specializations store the traits in a list of 9 items but then at the game UI they are split into 3 different columns. The players choose only 1 per column, so players tell others their choice as 2,2,1 instead of 2,5,8. In the first try I use the index of the trait position in the list and then use a replace function. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ah, got it. Then see my updated answer which simplifies that logic.

Comment: Easier to understand: The API saves the traits this way https://image.prntscr.com/image/3060e0f7b54a44029ecc86941650c2da.png and the choice there is 2,5,7 but players will read it as 2,2,1 so... that's what those numbers are. I need a way to store the positioning of the choice taken. EDIT: actually fail on my photoshop skills, it should starts on 0, not 1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `requests` library to fetch the JSON from your second code snippet. Here's an approach that works:

```
import requests

api_traits = requests.get("https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/traits%3Fids=1451%2C%201338%2C%201437%2C%2C1471%2C%201482%2C%201711%2C%2C2049%2C%202011%2C%201928%26lang=es").json()
api_specializations = requests.get("https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/specializations%3Fids=4%2C11%2C18%26lang=es").json()

traits_dict = { trait["id"]: trait["name"] for trait in api_traits }

for specialization in api_specializations:
    numeric_traits = []
    trait_names = []
    for i, trait_id in enumerate(specialization["major_traits"]):
        if trait_id in traits_dict:
            numeric_traits.append(i % 3 + 1)
            trait_names.append(traits_dict[trait_id])
    print("{} ({}): {}.".format(specialization["name"],
                                "".join(map(str, numeric_traits)),
                                ", ".join(trait_names)))

# Output:
# Fuerza (221): Fuerza restauradora, Mandoble eficaz, Potencia berserker.
# Tácticas (333): Potenciado, Potenciar aliados, Fuerza de falange.
# Berserker (111): Pendenciero aplastante, Reacción sangrienta, Rugido sangriento.
```

Three important things:

1. I made a dictionary mapping trait IDs to trait names. This lets you avoid the nested loops trying to match things up.
2. I used `enumerate` to avoid the `index` lookup when you're keeping track of which trait is in which position (for the "numeric traits").
3. I used modulo arithmetic to help with the numeric traits. `i % 3` gets the remainder when dividing by three (since the traits are in three columns), and then the `+ 1` simply gets back to 1-based indexes.

Let me know if anything else in the code is confusing.

Comment: Tested it and it works, with a slight modification: I changed the print for a list.append to store the 3 lanes, in order to return them 3.